# jQuery's mouseenter instead of on('mouseenter')

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to know how I can duplicate the following behaviour using jQuery's shortcut method of mouseenter apposed to using mouseenter via the on() jQuery method.

basic code below:
html

```
<dl>
    <dt>tab 1</dt>
    <dd>info.</dd>
    <dt>tab 2</dt>
    <dd>info.</dd>
    <dt>tab 3</dt>
    <dd>info.</dd>
</dl>
```

jQuery -

```
$('dl').on('mouseenter', 'dt', function() {
    $(this)
        .next()
            .slideDown(200)
});
```

so the above behaviour where only the 'dt' elements are in the jQuery collection using the below shortcut.

```
$('dl').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)
        .next()
            .slideDown(200)
});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZWsS/

thanks

Comment: read the docs for next()  http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are targeting `dt` elements under `dl` element, you need to use the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('dl dt').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).next().slideDown(200)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DKD3E/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is that I have many dt and dd elements. I only want to attach the event handler once (to the dl) otherwise it will slow down performance attaching it many, many times. Sorry I forgot to mention this before.

Comment: in that case you have to use `on` the `.mouseenter()` syntax does not allow event delegation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
$('dl').find('dt').mouseenter(function () {
   $(this).next().slideDown(200)
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/DKD3E/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but again this will attach the event handler to every dt I have correct? This will be a big performance hit unfortunately.